# Finding a primes combination of a number

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

Okay. So I wanted to do a simple program which would take a number from the user, and then it would list all the combinations (multiplications) of a prime numbers or their powers, which would give the inputed number as the result. For example:

For six : `2x3`, but for 550 : `2 x 5^2 x 11`

What would be the best mathematical algorithm there?

Comment: [Factoring algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) have been extensively studied.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Frynio, by "all the combinations". By the Unique Factorization Theorem, there's only one way to write a (positive integer) number as a product of primes, up to order.

Comment: Oh, so I'm stupid. So there is only one combination for one integer?